# replace parent theme images in child theme

Tags: child-theme, parent-theme

My images are found in the parent theme in this folder directory structure:

> public_html/wp-content/themes/listingpro/assets/images

I tried placing replacement images with the same name in the child theme under the same directory structure:

> public_html/wp-content/themes/listingpro-child/assets/images

The images continue to follow the parent theme's files.  Is there a way to replace the image files through the child theme?  Am I doing this wrong?

I am having the same issue when I place PHP files in same folder paths on the child theme.  Unless it is in the template folder, it doesn't affect the parent theme.

I imagine the two problems are related. Does this have something to do with the **functions.php** file?  I am a bit new to all of this so please bear with me!

Comment: This depends on how the parent theme is reverencing the files. Can you add a PHP code part where the parent theme is using the images?

Comment: The only files that, by default, you can replace in a child theme are templates from the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), header.php, footer.php searchform.php and comments.php. All other files aren't replaceable unless the parent theme specifically _allows_ them to be replaced. You can't just replace _any_ file from the parent theme in a child theme. That's a common misconception.